# Android eclipse plugin - cannot install and run build on hardware devices

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just created a new Android project in eclipse and hit build to run the test app on my phone. I enabled the "debuggable" option in my manifest. The phone's debug mode is enabled and it's listed on the devices list of adb. When hitting the build button on eclipse the following lines are printed out to the console:

> [2011-11-23 14:44:23 - Test] ------------------------------
>
> [2011-11-23 14:44:23 - Test] Android Launch!
>
> [2011-11-23 14:44:23 - Test] adb is running normally.
>
> [2011-11-23 14:44:23 - Test] Performing de.bobby.test.TestActivity activity launch
>
> [2011-11-23 14:44:23 - Test] Automatic Target Mode: using device '34334983F61800EC'
>
> [2011-11-23 14:44:23 - Test] Uploading Test.apk onto device '34334983F61800EC'
>
> [2011-11-23 14:44:23 - Test] Installing Test.apk...

And nothing happens.
The quiet strange thing is that I can install and run the app from the normal command line on Windows by calling "adb install APK_PATH" and "adb shell ...".
so obviously there is another problem with the eclipse plugin.

How can I fix that issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried restarting adb, restarting eclipse, and restarting your AVD?

Comment: I tried everything. All plugins and tools are up-to-date.

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating your AVD? Or just creating a new one and deploying to it?

Answer (score -2):

Try restarting Eclipse and ADB. If the problem remains, then go for updates of ADT and other tools.